# powershell regular expression cannot covert value

Tags: regex, powershell

Trying to achieve the below requirement with help of powershell and regex on windows 7 we are getting  process status output as like below from command prompt, we need convert these with below format using regex

```
PROCNAME   PRODPROC  Last Started 2012-05-23 11:45   Status RUNNING
lst Lag       00:00:00 (updated 00:00:00 ago)
```

Trying the below regular expression for getting:

```
PROCNAME PRODPROC  Status RUNNING  lst Lag 00:00:00 an updated 00:00:00
$regex=[regex] "PROCENAME\s*(?[a-zA-Z_0-9]+).+?Status\s(?[a-zA-Z]+).+?lst Lag(\s|\t)+(?((\d)+:\d{2}:\d{2})+).+?updated\s+(?((\d)+:\d{2}:\d{2})+)"
```

When we try to execute this , getting below error message

```
Cannot convert value “PROCENAME\s*(?[a-zA-Z_0-9]+).+?Status\s(?[a-zA-Z]+).+?lst
Lag(\s|\t)+(?((\d)+:\d{2}:\d{2})+).+?updated\s+(?((\d)+:\d{2}:\d{2})+)”
to type “System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex”. Error: “parsing “PROCNAME\s*(?[
a-zA-Z_0-9]+).+?Status\s(?[a-zA-Z]+).+?lst Lag(\s|\t)+(?((\d)+:\d{2}:\d{
2})+).+?updated\s+(?((\d)+:\d{2}:\d{2})+)” – Unrecognized grouping construct.”
But if we removed the ? ((?[a-zA-Z_0-9]+), (?[a-zA-Z]+) and ) , (\s|\t)+(?((\d)+:\d{2}:\d{2})+) and (?((\d)+:\d{2}:\d{2})+)
```

From the inside of the parenthesis it showing result but we unable to match that , but we need that string values for `$regex.GetGroupNames` as arguments.

We tried several way no luck, could you please help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Why would you want to process data as text (which is what regular expressions use) when PowerShell already (eg. output from `Get-Process`) is already typed (eg. Id properrty is already a number)?

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of groups that start `(?...)` which it complains about: `Unrecognized grouping construct`. Either omit them or add a `:` to make them non capturing groups:

```
$regex=[regex]"PROCNAME\s*(?:[a-zA-Z_0-9]+).+?Status\s(?:[a-zA-Z]+).+?lst Lag(\s|\t)+(?:((\d)+:\d{2}:\d{2})+).+?updated\s+(?:((\d)+:\d{2}:\d{2})+)"
```

Or specify the group names using `(?<groupName>.*)`:

```
$regex=[regex]"PROCNAME\s*(?<name>[a-zA-Z_0-9]+).+?Status\s(?<status>[a-zA-Z]+).+?lst Lag(\s|\t)+(?<started>((\d)+:\d{2}:\d{2})+).+?updated\s+(?<updated>((\d)+:\d{2}:\d{2})+)"
```